# CheckBox CheckedChanged event for all checkbox?

Tags: vb.net, loops, checkbox

is it possible to use the event for all checkboxes?
I have two Checkboxes, when I activate one the other is deactivated.
It goes in a loop.
when I try to deactivate a checkbox, the CheckedChanged of disactivaed checkbox is called and generate a loop error

```
        Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    
        Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim dt As DataTable
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            CheckBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
            Openconnection()
            da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM User WHERE " & Cbx_Filter.Text & " LIKE'" & Txt_Filter.Text & "%' and Stats = 'OK'", Connections)
        Else
            If CheckBox2.Checked = False Then
                Openconnection()
                da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM User WHERE " & Cbx_Filter.Text & " LIKE'" & Txt_Filter.Text & "%'", Connections)
            End If
        End If
        dt = New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        Connections.Close()
        da.Dispose()
```

and checkbox2

```
    Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
        Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim dt As DataTable
        If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
            CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
            Openconnection()
            da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM User WHERE " & Cbx_Filter.Text & " LIKE'" & Txt_Filter.Text & "%' and Stats = ''", Connections)
        Else
            If CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
                Openconnection()
                da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM User WHERE " & Cbx_Filter.Text & " LIKE'" & Txt_Filter.Text & "%'", Connections)
            End If
        End If

        dt = New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        Connections.Close()
        da.Dispose()

End Sub
```

Comment: It sounds like you want radiobuttons, not checkboxes.

Comment: "when I try to deactivate a checkbox, the CheckedChanged of disactivaed checkbox is called and generate a loop error"  This code does not produce an endless loop.  The problem is not shown in what you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thats easy. Just handle both events with one procedure:

```
Private Sub CheckBoxes_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
```

Then you have to code the differences, but you can test the sender:

```
Dim Chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
If Chk Is CheckBox1 then
    ' Do the stuff for CheckBox1
Else
    ' Do the stuff for CheckBox2
End If
```

Comment: Just saw it: The good old RadioCheckBox! Some client forced me to do this crap, too. But don't get into this stuff! Use the appropriate controls which are the RadioButtons! Ckeckboxes are designed to be independent from each other, not to switch off each other. Dont confuse the user!

Comment: This will not compile with Option Strict On which it should be.

Comment: Yes, the correct way with Option Strict On is `Dim Chk = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)`. Changed it.

Comment: Of for the RadioCheckBox, but I can't remove the selection by clicking on it again.

Answer (score 0):

Case option are:

1 - no one selected
2 - 1 of 2 selected

whith RadioCheckBox i cant uncheck the Radio after selection
with CheckBoxes i have a loop problem (i need to uncheck the other)

Comment: What about a third RadioButton called "None", which means the same as no one is selected? Or else you could use a ComboBox?

Comment: is possible to set a default value to a combox from display? if I do it from code, the text change event that I set on the value of combobox starts

Comment: I think, it's not possible. But what is wrong with `ComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0` in the `Form.Load` event?

Comment: if I set ComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0 in the form.load the change value event of the comboboxes is called

Comment: Well, you can suppress that having `Private Loading As Boolean = True`, in the `Form.Load` first `ComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0`, then `Loading = False` and in the `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged` event first do `If Loading Then Return`.